# Excel If function throws error even if there cant be anything wrong

Tags: microsoft-excel

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2I am newish to excel and tried using a simple If function.
The problem?
As soon as I enter Parameters into the function the function breaks with this message:
[image]
Translating to:
"There is an Issue with this formula. You don't want to enter a Formula?"...
Telling me to put it in Quotes.

I tried the Formulas from [the Microsoft help site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) -> same Message. 
I tried =IF(1=1,"true","false") -> same Message. 
I tried =IF() -> #NAME

-> An empty =IF() returns a logical answer -> cant evaluate function but as soon as I enter any parameters it breaks.

I don't even know where to look for an answer any more. Every solution tells me my function must have a logical flaw but 1=1 cant have a flaw.

What else can I try to get this to work???

Comment: you probably need to use `;` instead of `,` for you delimiter: `=IF(1=1;"true";"false")`

Comment: Yes it should be as above, although this https://easy-excel.com/excel-in-other-languages/excel-formulas-in-german/ site is saying to use `WENN` for `IF`

Comment: Agree to that, look out for more of those regional & locale dependent issues, differences that come from NOT having "en_US" region. Check "Region & Language" in Control panel.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With my setup, I needed to use "WENN" instead of "IF" and ";" instead of ",". I changed my Excel language to English so now I can use IF but the delimiter is still ";". Any Ideas on how to change that?

Comment: You can only change it for the entire PC, not just for Excel. Go to control panel/clock and region/additional settings and change the List separator from ";" to ","

Comment: Or in your case, probably: Systemsteuerung / Datums-, Uhrzeit- oder Zahlenformat ändern / Weitere Einstellungen / Listentrennzeichen